# Error in Pig: Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop', and try again

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to Start Pig-0.12.0 on MAC after I Installed Pig from Apache website.

Before I start Pig shell, I copied below 4 lines after creating pig-env.sh file in conf Directory.

```
Export JAVA_HOME=/usr
Export PIG_HOME=/Users/Hadoop_Cluster/pig-0.12.0
Export HADOOP_HOME=Users/Hadoop_Cluster/hadoop-1.2.1
Export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf/
```

Also, Added below text in pig.properties file:

```
Fs.default.name=hdfs://localhost:9000
Mapred.job.tracker=localhost:9001
```

I copied `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` and `mapped-site.xml` file from 
`Hadoop_home/conf` to `pig_home/conf`

I Get below Error when starting Pig in Command line under bin directory of Pig. Error says:

```
Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop', and Try again
```

Comment: What you did looks fine but the `export`s should be with lower case `e`.

Comment: Yes, I did tried with lower case "e" , "f" and "m" and also I did tried renaming the file from pig-0.12.0-withouthadoop.jar to pig-withouthadoop.jar. Still it did not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is not there copy `pig-0.12.0-withouthadoop.jar` (renamed or not, it shouldn't matter) to your `$PIG_HOME`, so in the end the file `/Users/Hadoop_Cluster/pig-0.12.0/pig-0.12.0-withouthadoop.jar` exists.

Also be careful about the lower case/upper case letters. Otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: Note that the important part here is to have `pig.jar` in `$PIG_HOME`, not necessarily the directory from which you're calling pig.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works.

All I did is rename the file in conf directory to "pig-withouthadoop.jar" instead of pig-0.12.0-withouthadoop. Also I make sure the hadoop is not in safe mode.

I kept the same settings as below in file below and all the 3 hdp files are 
copied to pig_home/conf directory.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr

export PIG_HOME=/Users/Hadoop_Cluster/pig-0.12.0

export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/Hadoop_Cluster/hadoop-1.2.1

export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/conf/
```

Comment: @majeed Can you please let me know what is the exact location of the jar file.I am not able to find that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error. Solved by removing **/bin** in the home patch in .bashrc .. source in bashrc and start pig..

```
export PIG_HOME=/home/hadoop/pig-0.13.0/bin ==> wrong
export PIG_HOME=/home/hadoop/pig-0.13.0  ==> correct..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow as per the error generated : 
Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop'

One needs to run the command ant jar-withouthadoop to get pig-withouthadoop.jar

if ant is not installed for ubuntu users try apt-get install ant.

The command ant jar-withouthadoop will take roughly 15 -20 mins, but one needs to be patient for getting this sorted.

I scratched my head all day.Kept looking for solutions on goggle none helped.

On extraction of the pig tar there is no jar that is created in the home directory.The above is to be followed to create the jar file and to run pig successfully.

I don't exactly know why this is done,but this is the solution that has worked for me with hadoop 1.2 [out of safe mode] and pig 0.12.1

Answer (score 0):

The key is find

```
pig-withouthadoop.jarpig-withouthadoop.jar\
```

in your `$pig_home.`

so use

```
find / -name *withouthadoop*
```

you can find it. maybe

```
pig-withouthadoop.jar
```

, you should rename it and cp to `$pig_home`. Worked for me